# Feature Identification for customer profiling

Tags: clustering, feature-selection, business-intelligence

Problem: I want to identify the characteristic(s) of people who would shop on Monday vs Sunday (or any such dichotomous response variable).

I have over a million observations and >50 variables/characteristics of customers in my data. I have this Day variable(binary) in my dataset too. Some of the variables are income intervals, age intervals, type of family,gender,Place of residence etc.(Not continuous data).

I am looking to answer this for example as following:People shopping on Sunday are: Florida-income range 50k-100k-family with kids-aged 30-45. Basically a profile of with as many characteristics to narrow down as possible.

Any help with the statistics/analytics methods that can be used in this context would be great.Thanks!

Comment: Hi Robin, welcome to CV! On this site there's no need to say "thank you" or "any help would be appreciated" at the end of your post - it might seem rude at first, but it's part of the philosophy of this site ([tour]) to "Ask questions, get answers, no distractions" and it means future readers of your question don't need to read through the pleasantries.

Answer (score 0):

You want interpretability in your model. Decision trees give you exactly that. You can use scikit-learn Decision trees, to get a tree which says for example if income range is less then 30k , they shop on Monday etc.